# Paypal Pre-approved Payments via Mobile Web UI?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

As of now, I'm able to link users to the desktop version of the payment preapproval page, where users can sign in or enter their payment information. Is there a mobile web version available?

Comment: Have you tested the same flow on a mobile device?  In my experience it'll automatically switch to the mobile experience when it identifies a mobile device.

Comment: Yes, I've tested the call on a mobile device, the URL being:
> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=

It doesn't automatically switch to the mobile version.

Forgot to mention that I need to allow users to use a guest account to pay; I recall one of the reasons why I dropped MPL was because it didn't support it

Answer (score 0):

here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/

"Because the Mobile Payment Libraries are build on PayPal's Adaptive Payments, you can accomplish many of the operations provided by that API with the MPL. For example, you can create mobile apps that provide for pre-approved and chained payments."